# autorun to current navigation params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx

Im trying to listen to changes in current navigation params.

I tried the following code:

```
@observer
export default class TestScreen extends Component<PropsType> {
  @computed get currParams(): ?Object {
    return this.props.navigation.state.params;
  }

  constructor(props: PropsType) {
    super(props);
    setTimeout(() => {
      props.navigation.setParams({ a: 'b' });
    }, 1500);

    this.aa = autorun(() => {
      console.log('currParams', this.currParams);
      console.log('a', this.currParams && this.currParams.a);
    });
  }

  render(): React$Element<any> {
    console.log('R', this.props.navigation.state.params);
    return (
      <View />
    );
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
currParams undefined
a undefined
R undefined
R undefined
R {a: "b"}
R {a: "b"}
```

meaning that the screen rendered with the new values but the autorun didn't saw that the params changed.

If I change the console.log in the render method to print this.currParams it prints undefined all the time.

How can I observe current navigation params?

Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because the navigation state is not observable.

`@computed` properties are only triggered to re-evaluate after one of the used `@observable` properties has been triggered.

Your render state does get triggered on changing Props and thus the render logs but not the mobx autorun (the render function is a react thing and triggered here on prop changed, the autorun only triggers on changes in mobx observable state).

Thus make sure the `this.props.navigation.state.params` is `@observable`. best make it observable at its root.

So in short: You can't use `@mobx.computed` on React.State. React state is not observed and thus wont trigger any changes in your Mobx State!

See here an example on how to use Mobx State directly in a react component: https://alexhisen.gitbooks.io/mobx-recipes/content/use-observables-instead-of-state-in-react-components.html

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create [solution](https://gist.github.com/LironErman/68fc6386295dede56fb25871fcd4515d) that works with autorun, I couldn't change the root state to be observable

Comment: @liron_e np, you can mark as answered if your question is answered.